# How could I remove xml elements in multiple files?

Tags: xml, bash

If I have multiple tags `<div class='hello'>...</div>` which I want to remove in **multiple files**, how could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `xmlstartlet`

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//div[@class="hello"]' <input.xml >output.xml
```

Wrap it around `find` to deal with multiple files.